# Json data has {d:"data"}

Tags: .net, jquery, wcf, json

I am writing jquery ajax code to call wcf service.

In this case WCf returns html as string.

**Some how when data is back in jquery it is in {d:"data"} format, What is this d element?**

*below is code*

```
$.get('<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/AjaxServices/ListingBrowse.svc/GetNewsHTML")  %> ',
  null,
  function(data) {
    alert(data);
    $('#newsdiv').html(data.d);
  },
  "html");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra "d" parameter is added by the .NET framework as an added security measure against XSS attacks ([source](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx)). It's included when the "Content-Type" of the request specifies "application/json".

Comment: Thanks for answer, i changed datatype to json and no more d element